# Spring application-context, not able to load (property-placeholder) .properties file

Tags: spring

I have a web-app, which loads a application-context files from many locations.

One of the application-context file is in a .jar file (this jar is present in WEB-INF/lib).

This application-context has an entry like this:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:META-INF/spring/default.app.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" ignore-resource-not-found="true"/>
```

But the default.app.properties is never found. I keep getting errors about 
Could not resolve placeholder 'db.driver' - something that is defined in default.app.properties and referred in application-context via ${db.driver}

It is almost as if property-placeholder is being ignored. I tried giving absolute path to my default.app.properties too.. even that wouldn't work.

Comment: are you sure the xml is loaded?

Comment: Yes the XML is loaded, because if i introduce an error in the context:property-placeholder (eg: rename location as locati) - i see an error.  Any ideas/hints - what can i try ?

Comment: how do you load the xmls? using `<import` ?

Comment: @Bozho 

WEB-INF/web.xml has these lines: 
<code>
<listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener> 

 <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>

        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/web-application-context.xml
            classpath*:META-INF/**/*context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
</code>

As a result there is a application-context.xml in a jar file in WEB-INF/lib. That gets loaded... and it has property-placeholder which just refuses to work.

Comment: @Bozho - Anything i can try and report back? Totally stuck here.

Comment: For example place the default app properties in `WEB-INF/classes` rather than in the jar, and see if it is located properly

Comment: @Bozho 
It does not work even with absolute path names like this: 
file:///d:/default.app.properties , i tried classes dir too, that too does not work.   Is it got to do with the fact that - since application-context is being loaded by web application from within a jar file, it ignores the property place holder for some reason. 

Something basic is wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you solved this problem? I've encoutered the same recently. My solution is simple and unlikely to be the case but... in my case there were two types of placeholders of different types. One type was configured using

`<context:property-placeholder/>`

the other type was configured as a bean of type ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. Removing one type of placeholder solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because Spring allow exist only one  <context:property-placeholder/>, When Spring find a <context:property-placeholder/>,it will ignore the remains. So put all the properties conf in one place.

reference to :http://www.iteye.com/topic/1131688